# Cannot Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I cannot upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04. The message on the screen is :

> "Not all updates can be installed".

And then I click partial upgrade. Then the message on the screen is :

> "Error authenticating some packages".

Then the upgrade fail. I try to upgrade many times but the two message always appear. I still can use 11.10 but always fail upgrade to 12.04. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some source of repository that makes troubles.
Make sure to have updated your apt repositories: in the terminal type `apt-get update`.

Then you can try typing in the terminal `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If there is some problem with the packages authentication you will be prompted a confirmation message to which you should answer yes.

Sometimes it happens also to me, even with normal upgrades, not distribution upgrade, because likely in the updating process there were problems. Maybe it can be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before an upgrade, you should install all updates.
But I advise against the upgrade! It makes things more complicated, because some packages are entirely different in new versions. Moreover, the risk of data loss is very high.

You can consider renewing the installation; it will keep your data and even personal settings. According [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes):

> Renewing the Installation without formating the partitons (in contrast to upgrading), will also keep the personal data and configurations under /home but will renew all system settings under /etc as well as the default set of installed packages.

Before renewing the installation, be sure that the /home directory is on a seperate partition; if not follow [the procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to do so.

**My experience:**

I *upgraded* 11.04 to 11.10 last year. Everything was OK, but the performance loss was sensible; for example, shutdown was taking more time (sometimes twice and sometimes four times more). Some days ago, I *installed* the new 12.04 without formatting the /home partition; I was surprised when I saw even my desktop backgraound was not changed.

I just needed to reinstall my apps; but not my preferences and data for those apps. For example, when I reinstall Tomboy Notes all of my notes appeared automatically without any backup or doing anything.